# Sublime text bad char for some "spaces" char

Tags: php, sublimetext3, sublimetext

i have a little problem with Sublime text : sometimes my spaces characters are not as usual and make php trigger an error.

When it occurs i CTRL+A my text, and i can see that for every classic space char there is a little dot, and for the one that make PHP fail there is nothing.

In this example, the first line is ok but the second one make my page error 500.

[image]

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''test2'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/.../test.php on line 6`

Of course in this example i copied/pasted the "bad space" char, but sometimes it just appears in my code for example after some } of ?

I haven't seen this issue and it's hard to find out on google since "Sublime text space problem" is not really easy to find ;)

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: it's not an issue. even I can see it in mine. But still works

Comment: It is just highlighting spaces. Its not a issue, its functionality of sublime to show spaces when you select.

Comment: install https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Gremlins to help find the non-standard whitespace characters, and replace them with a normal space char

Comment: When there is the dot it's ok, but when there is not php trigger an fatal error... this special space occurs sometimes after ? of } for example.

When i see the error on php i can find it but it could be easier if this special space did'nt occurs...

Comment: Here is the error triggered by php for the example in image : `Notice: Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' ' in /home/.../demo.php on line 84`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Keith Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473405/keith-hall), the [Gremlins package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Gremlins) help to find this unwanted character. Does not explain why they appears but helpfull tu find them easily.

@Abdulla Nilam & @Jigar Shah it's good be contributer to stackoverflow but it's not just a question of "how many answer you do", sometimes it's good to read the question too... it's not a race.

[edit] Thanks to Gremlins i found when theses characters are displayed : it's when you press ALT-GR + space. On french keyboards for example, to make a ] you press ALT-GR + ° and if you type "space" juste before and you didn't release ALT-GR, the space char is bad.

Il looks like it's un unbreakable space, like &nbsp in HTML : http://botcrawl.com/invisible-character-alt-codes-non-breaking-spaces/

[image]